# Recommended data structure of users with friends using Firebase?

Tags: ios, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know the best practices for structuring data in Firebase. After a user is authenticated and created his/her unique username, he/she should be able to add friend(s) to there friend list by a unique username.

Please take a look at what I have and I will make changes accordingly. Also, any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "post_id" : {
      "imgUrl" : "htttps://www.image.com/",
      "title" : "chicken"
    }
  },
  "posts_likes" : {
    "post_id" : {
      "user2" : true
    }
  },
  "posts_receiver" : {
    "post_id" : {
      "user2" : true
    }
  },
  "posts_sender" : {
    "post_id" : {
      "user1" : true
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "uid" : {
      "123kshdf8172321" : {
        "friends" : {
          "approved" : {
            "friend1" : "friend1uid",
            "friend2" : "friend2uid"
          },
          "pending" : {
            "friend3" : "friend3uid"
          }
        },
        "provider" : "facebook"
      }
    },
    "usernames" : {
      "username1" : "123kshdf8172321"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why you are making boolean every username and friend list ?

Comment: it is just to check which unique username has been taken quickly. I don't want to download too much data when checking for previous usernames

Comment: Currently it looks fine. to know more about best practices check this link https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I have updated my question as suggested